# word-spacing has a lot of whitespacing

Tags: html, css, wordpress, frontend

I'm having a hard time with Word-spacing on a clients wordpress website. They have a piece of content in flexbox but with the word-spacing is just messed up and resizing the website doesn't make it better at all!

[image: screenshot from website]

I'm getting on the right path slowly, but i just can't seem to figure it out on my own at the moment. Can somebody please explain why the word spacing is so messed up?

This is the code from the left box (they used a damm visual creator plugin VC)

```
<h4>Bedrijfsleven</h4>
[/vc_column_text][vc_separator type="transparent" up="5" down="0"]       
[vc_column_text]
<p style="text-align: justify;">SpaanIt geeft incompany-groepstraining 
en privéles in het Spaans en Italiaans op maat. In overleg wordt het 
huidige taalvaardigheidsniveau bepaald en waar de nadruk op komt te 
liggen tijdens de taallessen. Dat kan bijvoorbeeld Spaanse of Italiaanse 
spreekvaardigheid, schrijfvaardigheid en grammatica zijn. Daarnaast 
besteed SpaanIt aandacht aan cultuurverschillen en jargon.</p>

<p style="text-align: justify;">Ook biedt SpaanIt één-op-één   
VIP-arrangementen voor lessen Spaans of Italiaans. Er wordt dan van ’s 
morgens tot ’s avonds intensief op een afwisselende manier gewerkt aan
de taalvaardigheid. VIP-arrangementen vinden bij voorkeur plaats op een 
speciale locatie inclusief lunch en diner.</p>
[/vc_column_text][vc_separator type="transparent" up="15" down="0"]
[button size="small" icon="" target="_self" font_style="normal" 
font_weight="500" text_align="center" text="lees meer" 
link="http://www.spaanit.nl/bedrijven/" hover_color="#2f9738" 
border_color="#f9af00" hover_border_color="#2f9738" margin="20px 10px 
20px 5px" border_radius="25" color="#f9af00" background_color="#ffffff" 
hover_background_color="#ffffff"][/vc_column_inner][vc_column_inner 
width="1/4"][vc_single_image image="18394" img_size="260x250" 
qode_css_animation=""][vc_separator type="transparent" thickness="5"]
[vc_column_text css=".vc_custom_1454448677436{padding-top: -20px 
!important;}"]
```

I already tried just fixing the word-spacing

```
word-spacing: normal !important;
```

But without result.

Comment: Your words are unevenly spaced because you are using `text-align: justify`. Justified text will be spaced in a way that the first and last words of a row are align at the left and right edges respectively. The rest of the words in the row will be evenly distributed. Each row is treated as a separate entity meaning word spacing will be different between rows. TL;DR use `text-align: left;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This space not because `white spacing` but because you have inline style `text-align:justify;` you should remove it from `p element` or you can add this to your style to override it

```
text-align: initial !important;
```

Comment: "left" turned out to be the best solution for me, but still i thank you

Answer (score 1):

The reason there are so many whitespaces in the content is the fact that the `text-align` property of the element is set to `justify`, which makes sure that the rightmost and leftmost edges of each row of a text element are aligned perfectly.

You should either supplant `text-align: justify;` with `text-align: left;` or slightly alter the content so that it fits better with less whitespaces.